# Thread Safe Unit of Work with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, unit-of-work

I have a Data Layer that uses one Unit of work that is is basically a wrapper of the EnityFramework data context.

With all the async await stuff going around, I thought I'd start trying to use this data layer with some async calls.  (I'm new to asynchronous programming in general)

I quickly ran into the problem of "there is already an open data reader associated with this command" errors.

Is there a good way to make my Unit of work thread-safe?  Or should I just be creating another instance of it when i'm about to make some calls (in others words..be more careful).

Are there any good resources to check out for doing this?

My few google searches didn't amount to much, so I thought I'd bring this question to SO.

My Uow looks something like this.

```
public class MyUnitOfWork: IMyUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    private MyDbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    protected IRepositoryProvider RepositoryProvider;

    public MyUnitOfWork(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
    {
        CreateDbContext();


        repositoryProvider.DbContext = DbContext;
        RepositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;
    }

    public MyUnitOfWork(IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider, MyDbContext context)
    {
        DbContext = context;

        repositoryProvider.DbContext = DbContext;
        RepositoryProvider = repositoryProvider;

    }
    public void CreateDbContext()
    {
        DbContext = new MyDbContext();

        //Serialization false if we enable proxied entities
        DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        //avoid serilaization trouble
        DbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
    public void Commit()
    {
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IRepository<Person> Persons {get { return repositoryProvider.GetRepo<Person>(); } }

    public IRepository<SomeOtherEntityType> SomeOtherType {get { return repositoryProvider.GetRepo<SomeOtherEntityType>(); } }

    // IDisposable 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Entity Framework may be a bad choice for starting to play with `async`/`await` as its context isn't thread safe. To make it thread-safe you'll be best off wrapping your context in something that serializes DB calls which might be counter productive to your goal.

Comment: @StephenCleary no, this is EF5, although I could switch to EF6 if it offers me something I need without too much trouble.  This isn't used in any production code or anything yet.

Comment: EF6 is the first release that supports `async`.